# Update Multiple Post Meta for the Same Post In One call?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, theme-development, post-meta

How can I update multiple fields/Custom fields for the same post using only one call?

Everything I came across are cases of multiple calls of "update_post_meta", for each of the fields.

Is there a way to pass the data using an array, to update multiple post meta values (for the same post) using only one call?

I am trying the following but it doesn't seem to work, is it even possible to update multiple meta using the "wp_update_post"?

```
$New_Meta = array
        (
        'Client_Name'    => $Client_Name_Edit,
        'Client_Type'    => $Client_Type_Edit,
        );
wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $Post_ID,
            'post_name' => $Client_Name_Edit, 
            'post_title'=> $Client_Name_Edit,
            'meta_input'=> $New_Meta,
    ));
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't know about that way of doing it, but yes, it should work and your code looks correct. Maybe you want to post the rest of your code in case there's an error somewhere else. Perhaps $Post_ID is set wrong, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT: Original answer was inaccurate as you *can* do this with wp_update_post and the `meta_input` field**

As per the updated question and comments this is possible with `wp_update_post` (or `wp_insert_post` for a new record) using the `meta_input` key on the array, e.g.:

```
$metaValues = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2', 
    //   ... as many key/values as you want
);

wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $postId,
            'meta_input'=> $metaValues,
));
```

**Original Answer** (Works but no point doing it like this given above option)

Nope. [The docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) clearly show the function doesn't support that.

Obviously you can use an array to pass through many values if you have a bunch of things to do at the same time.

This is a PHP programming question, not a Wordpress question, but the code would look something like this:

```
$postId = 1234;

// Perhaps you have multiple key value pairs, like this:
$metaValues = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2', 
    //   ... as many key/values as you want
);

// Set all key/value pairs in $metaValues
foreach ($metaValues as $metaKey => $metaValue) {
    update_post_meta($postId, $metaKey, $metaValue);
}
```

Or this just to update the value on many keys:

```
// Or maybe you want to update a bunch of keys with the same value for some reason..
$metaValue = "10";
$metaKeys = Array("key1", "key2"); // as many keys as you want here

foreach($metaKeys as $metaKey) {
    update_post_meta($postId, $metaKey, $metaValue);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.

I have added a trial script which doesn't seem to work.
Is it not doable with wp_update_post or am I missing on something within the script?

Comment: `meta_input` with `wp_update_post ()` does exactly the same thing that mozboz's code does. It just loops over each key and runs `update_post_meta()`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about meta_input, thanks for the correction. Answer updated

Comment: yep, as Jacob says, this is, sadly, not anymore efficient - it calls wp_insert_post - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ and there in source code you can see

Answer (score 0):

You can also serialize the array

```
$metaValues = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2', 
    //   ... as many key/values as you want
);

update_post_meta($postId,'post_meta_name', serialize($metaValues));
```